# Opposite of Transition Matrix

Tags: markov-chains

I have a markov process with a transition matrix.  However, I'm studying certain the affect of *removing* certain transitions from the process.  My emphasis is on the transitions that are removed or prohibited. I'd like a terminology that reflects this emphasis.  I'd like to have a term to describe a matrix that prohibits certain selected transitions.   Some possibilities would be "prohibited transitions matrix", but that has a clunky sound.  do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I would suspect that there doesn't exist a widely used term for this, since, at the core of the operation, you're just changing the chain(s).

Comment: HI scoopfaze,  for the purpose of writing my paper, I have decided to call it a rejection rule.  The meaning is that some selected transitions are "rejected".   Does that sound reasonable to you?  I decided not to go with "exclusion" rule, because it could be confused with the Pauli Exclusion principle, which states that a particle can't transition into a state that is allready occupied with a particle of the same spin.  So that is different than the concept I'm trying to describe.

Comment: You can call it whatever you’d like. I was just trying to explain why I don’t think you’ll find an established name for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a term, "transition exclusion matrix" or "exclusion matrix".   However, I dont' really like that term.